# How to circumvent same-origin policy for a 3rd party https site?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I have a `http://` site that needs to access a 3rd party JSON API that is exposed on an `https://` site. I've read through [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy), but it seems the methods described there aren't appropriate for me:

1. **The document.domain method** - only works on subdomains.
2. **The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing method** - requires server cooperation.
3. **The window.postMessage method** - seems to require opening a popup window?
4. **The Reverse Proxy method** - A possible solution, but seems a bit too hard to setup.
5. **http://anyorigin.com** - seems to not support SSL.

Is this it? Must I implement solution 4, which seems rather complicated, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you CURL the result from the other site with a regular PHP page on your own domain and then grab the JSON from that PHP page?

Comment: Wouldn't [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) work here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure anyorigin.com supports SSL. Try fetching `https://test.kems.net/`, for example - it works just fine.

Comment: I am not a JSON expert, but I think you should give some more information about the "3rd party JSON API that is exposed on an https:// site.". How flexible is it?

Comment: @curiosguy - this is the API. Not very flexible. https://mtgox.com/api/0/data/ticker.php

Comment: @David - my bad, thanks! I posted this as an answer.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco - Hmm, it worked fine for a few weeks, but now it started to return null for _some_ https sites. Try feeding `https://bitcointalk.org/` to anyorigin for example.

Comment: **I wrote an answer for this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, it seems that anyorigin.com **does** support https.

The reason I naively thought it doesn't, is because the [API in question](https://mtgox.com/api/0/data/ticker.php) returns JSON, and I thought I would actually just get a plain text response (as in my tests with using anyorigin.com on google.com). When it returned just an `object`, I figured something was broken.

It appears the object simply returns the parsed JSON, so I'm good to go!

**Update** - anyorigin.com stopped working with some https sites a few weeks after I posted this, so I went ahead and wrote [whateverorigin.org](http://whateverorigin.org), an open source alternative to anyorigin.

Comment: @RobW - please open an issue on github. I will investigate this on Friday (can't promise anything sooner) - https://github.com/ripper234/Whatever-Origin

Comment: those methods won't work if the remote server returns different content based on who requests something. For example YouTube returns a webpage for a video from which you can extract a playback URL say for MP4 that will only work (say to fetch as .mp4 file) if used from the caller, not from a client of the caller (when caller is a proxy)

Comment: **I wrote an answer for this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)** – _the last one, supports https_

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ajax-cross-origin a jQuery plugin. With this plugin you use jQuery.ajax() cross domain.

It is very simple to use:

```
    $.ajax({
        crossOrigin: true,
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

You can read more here: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

Answer (score 0):

JSONP should be on your list, and higher up.  Pretty much the standard.  It requires server cooperation, but most any API should know what they're doing and support it.

[here](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) is a real basic writeup of how it works